# Table content spacing vertical when changing active Pill

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

in generally im trying to load 3 diferent tables depending on the active pill, for example i click in first year and it shows me a table with the first year grades and other things, the proble is that when i load the first table, everything is fine, when i load the second, i get a vertical space between the pill and the table, and in the last table i get a even bigger vertical space, i dont know why it happens.

**Here is my code**

```
<div class="row spacing2">
        <h3 id="PlanoEstudos">Plano de Estudos</h3>
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active">
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#ano1">1ºano</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#ano2">2ºano</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a data-toggle="tab" href="#ano3">3ºano</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">
                <table id="ano1" class="table tab-pane fade in active">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Unidade Curricular</th>
                            <th>Tipologia</th>
                            <th>ECTS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>MatemáticaI</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Algoritmia e Estrutura de dados</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sistemas Computacionais</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Tecnologias e aplicações web</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Fundamentos de design</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>MatemáticaII</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Conceção e produção multimédia</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Programação orientada a objetos</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Design Gráfico</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ProjetoI</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                     <table id="ano2" class="table tab-pane fade">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Unidade Curricular</th>
                            <th>Tipologia</th>
                            <th>ECTS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Análise e modelação de sistemas</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Bases de dados</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Física aplicada à programação</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Programação webI</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Animação gráfica</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Engenharia de software</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Modelação e ambientes 3D</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Programação webII</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sistemas gráficos</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>ProjetoII</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <table id="ano3" class="table tab-pane fade">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Unidade Curricular</th>
                            <th>Tipologia</th>
                            <th>ECTS</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Sistemas cistribuidos</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>7</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ergonomia cognitiva e design de interação</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>5</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Desenvolvimento de jogos</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Negócio eletrónico e segurança</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Gestão empresarial</td>
                            <td>1.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>6</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Técnicas avançadas de web design</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Inovação e empreendedorismo</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Programação para dispositivos móveis</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>4</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Projeto final/estágio</td>
                            <td>2.ºSemestre</td>
                            <td>20</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PS: i followed this link to do this [enter link description here](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_pills_dynamic&stacked=h)

Comment: Your code seems to work as is https://jsfiddle.net/qrbooqzp/ if libraries are properly loaded

Comment: You have a custom class defined in your wrapper `<div class="row spacing2">`, do you a have custom style sheet other than vanilla Bootstrap, and have you checked the style sheet for possible causes?